"Error Handling: How do I resolve the 'prompt does not exist' issue when using OpenAI's complete() function?"
`
server side logic 
route.tsx
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import openai from "openai";
import OpenAI from "openai";

const configuration = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

export async function POST(req: Request): Promise<NextResponse> {
  try {
    const { userId } = auth();
    const body = await req.json();
    const { message } = body;

    if (!userId) {
      return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }
    if (!configuration.apiKey) {
      return new NextResponse("OpenApi KEy is not configured", { status: 500 });
    }
    if (!message) {
      return new NextResponse("Message Are Required", { status: 400 });
    }

    const response = await configuration.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
      prompt: message,
    
    });

    return NextResponse.json(response.data.choices[0].message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("[CONVERSATION_ERROR", error);
    return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
  }
}


`

route-->api/conversation
Page.tsx
"use client";

import * as z from "zod";
import axios from "axios";
import { MessageSquare } from "lucide-react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { ChatCompletionRequestMessage } from "openai";

import { Heading } from "@/components/heading";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";


import { formSchema } from "./constants";

const ConversationPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<ChatCompletionRequestMessage[]>([]);

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      prompt: ""
    }
  });

  const isLoading = form.formState.isSubmitting;
  
  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      const userMessage: ChatCompletionRequestMessage = { role: "user", content: values.prompt };
      const newMessages = [...messages, userMessage];
      
      const response = await axios.post('/api/conversation', { messages: newMessages });
      setMessages((current) => [...current, userMessage, response.data]);
      
      form.reset();
    }
     catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error)
    } finally {
      router.refresh();
    }
  }

  return ( 
    <div>
      <Heading
        title="Conversation"
        description="Our most advanced conversation model."
        icon={MessageSquare}
        iconColor="text-violet-500"
        bgColor="bg-violet-500/10"
      />
      <div className="px-4 lg:px-8">
        <div>
          <Form {...form}>
            <form 
              onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} 
              className="
                rounded-lg 
                border 
                w-full 
                p-4 
                px-3 
                md:px-6 
                focus-within:shadow-sm
                grid
                grid-cols-12
                gap-2
              "
            >
              <FormField
                name="prompt"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-10">
                    <FormControl className="m-0 p-0">
                      <Input
                        className="border-0 outline-none focus-visible:ring-0 focus-visible:ring-transparent"
                        disabled={isLoading} 
                        placeholder="How do I calculate the radius of a circle?" 
                        {...field}
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
              <Button className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-2 w-full" type="submit" disabled={isLoading} size="icon">
                Generate
              </Button>
            </form>
          </Form>



          
        </div>
        <div className="space-y-4 mt-4">
          {/* {isLoading && (
            <div className="p-8 rounded-lg w-full flex items-center justify-center bg-muted">
              <Loader />
            </div>
          )}
          {messages.length === 0 && !isLoading && (
            <Empty label="No conversation started." />
          )} */}
          <div className="flex flex-col-reverse gap-y-4">
            {messages.map((message) => (
              <div 
                key={message.content} 
                className={cn(
                  "p-8 w-full flex items-start gap-x-8 rounded-lg",
                  message.role === "user" ? "bg-white border border-black/10" : "bg-muted",
                )}
              >
                {/* {message.role === "user" ? <UserAvatar /> : <BotAvatar />} */}
                <p className="text-sm">
                  {message.content}
                </p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   );
}
 
export default ConversationPage;



Certainly! You can write a message as follows:
Hello,
I'm encountering an error in my application. When making a POST request to the api/conversation endpoint, I'm receiving a 500 Internal Server Error. Here's the error message:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
This error seems to originate from page.tsx at line 45, with the specific request URL being POST http://localhost:3000/api/conversation.
Could anyone please assist me in diagnosing and resolving this issue?
Thank you.
